# знак препинания перед "лишь"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нужно ли ставить тире в данном примере: "Ведь все тексты о нас с ней — лишь куча бумажного хлама".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ведь все тЕксты **о нас с ней — лишь** куча бумажного хлАма.*

Тире в таком предложении следует поставить, хотя по правилам при наличии частицы или других слов  тире между подлежащим и сказуемым может не ставиться.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Примечание. Обычно тире не ставится: 4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, **иногда — наречие, союз, частица.** 5) если перед сказуемым стоит относящийся к нему второстепенный член предложения:

Задачи по этой теме решаются с учетом интонации и наличии паузы между группой подлежащего и сказуемого.  В данном случае следует обозначить границу между ними ввиду распространенности первой части: к подлежащему относится оборот ***о нас с ней*** в роли несогласованного определения.